# Button is not reactive to changes to slideBar input in Shiny app

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to let shiny do a calculation with the slide bar value after the user clicks on the action button. After the action button has been clicked, the app should then show a message. At the moment I've got the following code running, but after you click the Action Button for the first time, it will automatically re-execute when the reactive slide bars change. Does someone have a suggestion to make it so that the action button must be clicked every time the slide bar input changes?

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    div(
      id = "form",
      sliderInput("popDensity", "What is the population density?", value=0, min=0, max=1500),
      
      actionButton("button", "Evaluate", style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4")
      
    ),
    div(
      id = "sidebar",
      sidebarPanel(
                   uiOutput("calculation")   ) )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    likelihood<-reactive({(1/500)*input$popDensity})
    
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      
      output$calculation<-renderUI({
        if (likelihood()>1) {
          a <- paste("<span style=color:red> be careful! </span>")
        }
          else if (likelihood()>.65){
            a <- paste("<span style=color:orange> be careful! </span>")
          }
        else if (likelihood()>.35){
          a <- paste("<span style=color:yellow> be careful! </span>")
        }
        else if (likelihood()>.10){
          a <- paste("<span style=color:blue> be careful! </span>")
        }
               else {
          a <- paste("<span style=color:green> be careful! </span>")
        }
        HTML(a)
        
      })
    })  
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the UI to update only when the button is clicked, then `likelihood` doesn't need to be reactive.  So you can write your server function as

```
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      likelihood<-(1/500)*input$popDensity
      output$calculation<-renderUI({
        if (likelihood>1) {
          a <- paste("<span style=color:red> be careful! </span>")
        }
        else if (likelihood>.65){
          a <- paste("<span style=color:orange> be careful! </span>")
        }
        else if (likelihood>.35){
          a <- paste("<span style=color:yellow> be careful! </span>")
        }
        else if (likelihood>.10){
          a <- paste("<span style=color:blue> be careful! </span>")
        }
        else {
          a <- paste("<span style=color:green> be careful! </span>")
        }
        HTML(a)
      })
    })  
  }
```

and get the effect you want.

Alternatively, if `likelihood` needs to remain reactive for reasons you haven't explained, then you need to isolate it from its dependency on the slider and introduce a dependency on the button into the `renderUI` call.  Both are easy to do.

You can isolate a widget from a dependency on an input using `isolate`:

```
likelihood<-reactive({(1/500)*isolate(input$popDensity)})
```

Introducing the dependency on the button is equally easy: just add a reference to `input$button` anywhere in the `renderUI` call.  This is often done at the top of the call:

```
output$calculation<-renderUI({
  input$button
  <your existing code here>
})
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I make it so that the span line is not as redundant? I just want to replace it with one line where I just get to replace the different colors.